# How should I use torch.compile properly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm currently trying to use pytorch 2.0 for boosting training performance with my project. And I've heard that torch.compile might be boost some models.

So my question (for now) is simple; how should I use torch.compile with large model?

Such as, should I use torch.model like this?

```py
class BigModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(BigModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            SmallBlock(), 
            SmallBlock(), 
            SmallBlock(), 
            ...
        )
        ...

class SmallBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(SmallBlock, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            ...some small model...
        )

model = BigModel()
model_opt = torch.compile(model)
```

,or like this?

```py
class BigModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(BigModel, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            SmallBlock(), 
            SmallBlock(), 
            SmallBlock(), 
            ...
        )
        ...

class SmallBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(SmallBlock, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            ...some small model...
        )
        self.model = torch.compile(self.model)

model = BigModel()
model_opt = torch.compile(model)
```

For summary,

1. Should compile each layer? or torch.compile do this automatically?
2. Is there any tips for using torch.compile properly?

To be honest, I tried both, but there are no differences..

And also, it didn't speed up dramatically, I just checked speed up rate for my model just about 5 ~ 10%.

Answer (score 5):

PyTorch dev here but there's a lot of variables to your question

1. What kind of hardware are you using? speedups will be most dramatic on A100 or A10G GPU
2. If yes did you enable tensor cores?
3. Compilation happens during the first batch, what was your batch size? If small then indeed using mode=reduce-overhead would indeed make things faster because it enables CUDA graphs which help reduce the overhead of launching small kernels
4. You should opt to compile the whole model that you're actually running, in practice we have some utilities to allow or disallow compilation of subgraphs that you can check out here https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_dynamo.html

Answer (score 0):

the default mode of torch.compile does not seem to work, but it has another mode that can really accelerate your model.
"""
torch.compile(${yourmodel}, mode="reduce-overhead")
"""

Comment: What does this do, exactly?